# Semi-colon usage

Tags: semicolons

Has this semi-colon been used correctly?  If not, how should this sentence read?
Thank you.

This brew is a result of passion, hard work, and commitment; connecting family, friendships and good times.

Comment: I'd use a dash rather than a semicolon in your context, because I normally expect what follows the semicolon to be a syntactically complete sentence (which yours isn't).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Personally, I would use 'which connect' rather than a semi-colon and 'connecting' but I am interested to see what others think. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that it would feel better if the semi-colon were connecting two independent clauses and suggested: "..and commitment; it connects family..."

The sentence is being used on a product label and has been a point of contention.

Comment: The temptation to use the semicolon here is doubtless to avoid further comma overload; FF's suggestion is the ideal solution.

Comment: I suggest that semi-colon isn't at all wrong but neither is it in any way necessary.

Depending on choice of style, not rules, why would you not as easily either use a simple comma, or drop any punctuation mark, please?